# How to find if a number is in an array?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, methods, boolean

Trying to write a method to tell me if a number is in an array or not. So far I have..

```
    public static boolean inList(double number, double[] list){
    for (double i : list)
        {
            if (i == number){
                return false;
        }

    }
    return true; //if its not in the array I want the if statement to run.
}
```

So far this hasn't worked for me, for some reason it can't identify when some numbers are in the array or not.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have your `return` statements the wrong way around? If `i == number`, surely `number` is in the array, so it should return true?

Comment: Often you'll need to know the index of the value, so you could return  the index if you find the number, or -1 if not.

Answer (score 6):

You mixed up your `return` statements.  It should be so:

```
    public static boolean inList(double number, double[] list){
        for (double i : list)
        {
            if (i == number){
                //return true when you've found the match!
                return true;
            }
        }
    //return false here because you finished looking at the entire array 
    //and couldn't find a match.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But I want it to trigger the if statement if the number is not found. My if statement is if (inList(in,numbersArray))

Comment: Do `if(!inList(in,numbersArray)) `.  `!` will negate the returned `boolean` value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to swap the true and false in your code.

If you have equality there, then it's in the list, otherwise it is not in the list.

Also, generally don't compare doubles `a` and `b` with `==`. Use

something like: `Math.abs(a - b) < EPS`, where `EPS = 0.00001` let's say.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to think of when comparing doubles is that they are not entirely distinct in their representations. This means that 1.0 + 2.0 not nescessarily equals 3.0, but could equal 2.999999.... or 3.000001.

A good thing would be to use a comparision which allowed a little slack (an epsilon) that made it possible to have the value you compare with to some (very close) distance to the numbers you compare with.

So something like:

```
public static boolean inList(double number, double[] list){
    for (double i : list)
        {
            if (Math.abs(i - number) < 0.0000000001){
                return true;
        }

    }
    return false; //if its not in the array I want the if statement to run.
}
```

Comment: +1 Because this is a common issue, like comparing a double with integer 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do serious stuff with java arrays, don't miss [java.util.Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)!

A function for finding a number in a (sorted) array would be:

```
double[] theArray = {1.24, 5.23, 1.1, 6.466, 35.1, 34.0};
java.util.Arrays.sort(theArray); //for binarySearch to work

public static boolean inArray(double i, double[] theSortedArray){
     return (java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(i, theSortedArray) >=0);
}
```

Comment: From time complexity point of view this sounds terrible. So to find a value, let's sort first O(N logN), and then do a binary search (O logN). I don't know, sounds like overkill.

Comment: It depends on if you want to do the search very many times on a common set of values (which is quite a common use case).

Comment: Right, in that case yes. OK.